# Create tiles given images and locations; convert markers to tiles

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, gis, openstreetmap, leaflet

I've developed a HTML application that displays a map. This map has many fixed markers (they do not change in time).
Due to that:

1. I want to speed up the application
2. I want to hide the marker position from malicious users (so they can't use the information I've gathered for they're own porpose)

I want to convert the markers to a tile layer.

I've been googleing without success how to do this. Anyone has faced this problem and has a nice easy solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the markers never change, there is a great solution:
[Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com/).

You can create your map with the markers, then the mapbox servors will send the tiles with the markers.

Comment: Sorry, this does not cover my needs. 1st is a paid option. Second, can 't be generated from data given data. 3rd icons are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadkey. It'similar to a quadtree. You can download my PHP class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It also uses a quadkey.